# So many Grubs for only 2 distros... What should I do?

Tags: fedora, grub2, dual-boot, opensuse, boot-loader

I have two hard disks, one HDD (`/dev/nvme0n1`) and one SSD (`/dev/sda`).

The first one contains mainly Fedora, and the second one mainly OpenSUSE Tumbleweed. The details are below:

- [GParted /dev/nvme0n1](https://i.imgur.com/2tVgGds.png)
- [GParted /dev/sda](https://i.imgur.com/SC4INbg.png)

Both screenshots above were taken from OpenSUSE Tumbleweed (on sda1).

And for good measure, here’s the Boot section of my Bios:

- [Bios Boot section](https://i.imgur.com/1ne3Rec.jpg)

---

************************************************************************My goal is: one grub, for everything************************************************************************ (Tumbleweed, Fedora, Advanced options for both, Bios, and Tumbleweed snapshots). But here’s what I have instead…

---

When I do Ctrl+F12 at boot, here are the choices I have:

- [Boot Manager](https://i.imgur.com/0AWLLs9.jpg)

Let's go through in order:

1. If I select `opensuse` (the first or the gourth one), I get greeted by a nice Grub:

   - [Tumbleweed’s Grub](https://i.imgur.com/B8NcdCn.jpg)

   …where every entry works, and that has the desired look. Only problem: no Fedora in the choices...
2. If I select `Fedora` (the second entry), I get to this Grub:

   - [Fedora's Grub](https://i.imgur.com/boYVEr8.jpg) (I apologize for the quality, you all know how hard it is to take a photo of this kind of screen…)

I tried my best to even just change the background from Fedora’s Gub config files, but nothing worked, not even changing the timeout… Which makes me think I might not be seeing the right Grub?

In that one, any of the first 3 Fedora entries will boot properly to Fedora, but the 4th one will launch Bios. And the opensuse entry...

…redirects me to a glitched version of the one from above:

- [Glitched Tumbleweed Grub](https://i.imgur.com/c5PrtjS.jpg)

It looks just like the Fedora Grub on top of the Tumbleweed Grub, doesn’t it?
Here, **none** of the entries works (aside from the UEFI ones), they all give me errors in a black window in the middle of my display for a few seconds, and then redirect me to the glitched Grub. After a while, the graphical interface even completly disappears, leaving with a black screen where I can show the options one at a time, using the arrow keys:

- [Black glitched Grub…](https://i.imgur.com/SEgbJlp.jpg)

Finally, if I choose the 3rd entry from the Boot Manager (`Linux Boot Manager`) (which I suppose comes from a failed attempts to install `systemd-boot`), I only get [a black screen with one option: “Reboot into firmware’s interface”](https://i.imgur.com/yVYgvrM.jpg), that leads me into the Bios.

In fact I’m facing so many different Grubs that here’s a photo of one I don’t even remember how I got to:

- [Mystery Tumbleweed Grub](https://i.imgur.com/R6pEy2C.jpg)

---

So, last few words:

- I know, I have 2 EFI partitions (one on each disk), and that’s completely stupid. I didn’t know what I was doing when I created the second one (the one on `sda`), I was confused about how “Grub with EFI” worked… Anyway, that may be part of the problem.

Other problems are:

- in Tumbleweed, I can make changes to grub2 by editing `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`, and they are effective; however, if I try to run the command:
  `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`
  I get the error:

```
insmod: ERROR: could not load module part_msdos: No such file or directory
```

So my Grub here kind of works, but kind of doesn’t work either…

I tried adding Fedora by copying the contents of `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` into `etc/grub.d/40_custom`, or even directly into `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`, but though I managed to make a Fedora entry ******appear****** in the Grub menu, I never managed to boot from it.

From the other side, I can update Grub in Fedora (by which I mean I see no error, and it says it detects UEFI and Tumbleweed), but no change I make in `/.../grub2/themes/Fedora/theme.txt`, or in `/etc/default/grub`, seems to be effective (as I said, I can’t even change the default timeout…)

---

**I posted the contents of my config files in [this Gitlab snippet](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/3613716).**

---

So any ideas as to how to build **one Grub to rule them all**, are welcome! And if you read this **thanks** for taking the time to read my post to the end!

Comment: I prefer to have an ESP on every drive for any installs on that drive. I turn off os-prober in Ubuntu (as I have multiple installs) and only add the entries I want into 40_custom. Ubutnu offers a link to most current kernel, so you can have a fixed 40_custom entry to always boot most current kernel. Not sure if Fedora or OpenSuse offer that. But then you have to update both after kernel update to be sure to have updated grub file. See `sudo efibootmgr -v` for UEFI boot entries. Best to have one for each install. Some may apply:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen

Comment: Thank you. I've made a lot of progress since the post, but I have one question for you: how to you edit UEFI boot entries? I'm a bit confused I fixed everything related to EFI but I still have 2 Fedora in my Boot Manager (and 2 Fedora and one inexistant Debian in `sudo efibootmgr -v`...). Thanks!

Comment: See `man efibootmgr` and -b XXXX B More info. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228 Assumes your Linux uses same or similar efibootmgr, as recently only have used Ubuntu & its flavors.

Comment: (I don't see my last comment so I'm going to say it again): thanks, with `efibootmgr` I was able to remove abherent entries (Windows, Debian), and one of the two duplicates of Fedora. My Boot Manager is cleaner now.
However, that does not really help with my problem (in the post)...

Comment: If OpenSuse or Fedora do not have links in /boot to most current kernel, you just about have to just boot into both installs when either updates, so os-prober can include newer kernel from other install. And last one run will normally be default, but you can use efibootmgr to change boot order with -o parameter.